# Can Google device manager turn location on automatically?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, geolocation

For battery saving purpose is there any way to google device manager turn location on when we need it (Like when I search "Find my phone")???

Comment: This feature is not implemented yet. You must have GPS turned on.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at the moment, may be you could add this to feature request in the Google Product forums.